# redirect Issue post MFA

Tags: two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication, identity-verification

We have implemented 2FA for partner community user. Since then we are facing an issue while trying to render pdf in a VF page.Here is the flow

After successful login through 2FA, "Partner community user" clicks on a Next button, a queueable class generates a pdf and sends it to 3rd part DMS. When we tried to view the pdf in SF from DMS UI, it threw an error saying **"pdf could not be loaded"**.Initially we thought that the pdf was corrupted but after opening it in a notepad, we found below.Basically its redirecting to some Identity query string.If I simply launch ***https//mydomain.force.com/_ui/identity/verification....*** , the pdf renders.

How can we get this bypassed in VF when 2FA is ON

````
function redirectOnLoad() {
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('/_ui/identity/verification/policy/VerificationStartUi/e?sea=0&vcsrf=Qr7TJnRRPIspy9XwaUKe8Qj_f4CjlMeJJJBzOTObXFlSh2MGwpfogyOqCl1-bZQIhdHzlt74JRc-mc5TWSf25BzLch6maFEpqJxT2mJaJP9W24PCZrhOAUrrUDXRsCKkkj3f1V1gFYl-hXBdfmu_5Mh0vwc8P3NYoebKUm33iSVschvb0QK-BNdNsglIxnOOFW1aCVUVj0Xc2uD_TgBLtM3TPcSmwMGq3Sbzm1WYF2CzC7H_2S03IeSXj2sdEVU1Utnd1JLCd34xYxCj2wKBrvGEo1R6SvRnUGUE9wnK2rKbVRQ40Rq9VDgoa2ip_ZDrprQZ91vuWI9KXCwEH6aKtTZr4OegjM5in2_fvkTULM1DFh21CuBMvUJKF3EQOruR2Hrc-7uXJNg3SdJEFoyYyx8equiYp0zSDLuwYDSVdlLcz-ogfBz0g_AbwoJgq31mErpZH8Yb22-XQa_HXzzUdQtwRxXPrfo-uNDaNEb7Yns0p1kpurfsxDwk7n5-YgxbgRmTlE3yt3rdVGQNcR26GJbR9yypv5OHVVk4ys9V3kyDxYgSZTI9BjJbzaOzzomGPjirSqGhgIzxTga8TrkGhEQJd4t1e2P9bfzu4D1jD-wzUQw6lNHTrgWMrZpkAnfHezegtEzRLNPMbYnEt1R1oSgwWZWLX-QXAVBlwq_jlE%3D&vpol=pe&vflid=0&retURL=%2Fapex%2FMF_DP_PDFGenerator%3FassetId%3Da330I00000L8EzhQAF%26inline%3D1'); }  else 
if (window.location.replace){ 
window.location.replace('/_ui/identity/verification/policy/VerificationStartUi/e?sea=0&vcsrf=Qr7TJnRRPIspy9XwaUKe8Qj_f4CjlMeJJJBzOTObXFlSh2MGwpfogyOqCl1-bZQIhdHzlt74JRc-mc5TWSf25BzLch6maFEpqJxT2mJaJP9W24PCZrhOAUrrUDXRsCKkkj3f1V1gFYl-hXBdfmu_5Mh0vwc8P3NYoebKUm33iSVschvb0QK-BNdNsglIxnOOFW1aCVUVj0Xc2uD_TgBLtM3TPcSmwMGq3Sbzm1WYF2CzC7H_2S03IeSXj2sdEVU1Utnd1JLCd34xYxCj2wKBrvGEo1R6SvRnUGUE9wnK2rKbVRQ40Rq9VDgoa2ip_ZDrprQZ91vuWI9KXCwEH6aKtTZr4OegjM5in2_fvkTULM1DFh21CuBMvUJKF3EQOruR2Hrc-7uXJNg3SdJEFoyYyx8equiYp0zSDLuwYDSVdlLcz-ogfBz0g_AbwoJgq31mErpZH8Yb22-XQa_HXzzUdQtwRxXPrfo-uNDaNEb7Yns0p1kpurfsxDwk7n5-YgxbgRmTlE3yt3rdVGQNcR26GJbR9yypv5OHVVk4ys9V3kyDxYgSZTI9BjJbzaOzzomGPjirSqGhgIzxTga8TrkGhEQJd4t1e2P9bfzu4D1jD-wzUQw6lNHTrgWMrZpkAnfHezegtEzRLNPMbYnEt1R1oSgwWZWLX-QXAVBlwq_jlE%3D&vpol=pe&vflid=0&retURL=%2Fapex%2FMF_DP_PDFGenerator%3FassetId%3Da330I00000L8EzhQAF%26inline%3D1');
} else {
window.location.href ='/_ui/identity/verification/policy/VerificationStartUi/e?sea=0&vcsrf=Qr7TJnRRPIspy9XwaUKe8Qj_f4CjlMeJJJBzOTObXFlSh2MGwpfogyOqCl1-bZQIhdHzlt74JRc-mc5TWSf25BzLch6maFEpqJxT2mJaJP9W24PCZrhOAUrrUDXRsCKkkj3f1V1gFYl-hXBdfmu_5Mh0vwc8P3NYoebKUm33iSVschvb0QK-BNdNsglIxnOOFW1aCVUVj0Xc2uD_TgBLtM3TPcSmwMGq3Sbzm1WYF2CzC7H_2S03IeSXj2sdEVU1Utnd1JLCd34xYxCj2wKBrvGEo1R6SvRnUGUE9wnK2rKbVRQ40Rq9VDgoa2ip_ZDrprQZ91vuWI9KXCwEH6aKtTZr4OegjM5in2_fvkTULM1DFh21CuBMvUJKF3EQOruR2Hrc-7uXJNg3SdJEFoyYyx8equiYp0zSDLuwYDSVdlLcz-ogfBz0g_AbwoJgq31mErpZH8Yb22-XQa_HXzzUdQtwRxXPrfo-uNDaNEb7Yns0p1kpurfsxDwk7n5-YgxbgRmTlE3yt3rdVGQNcR26GJbR9yypv5OHVVk4ys9V3kyDxYgSZTI9BjJbzaOzzomGPjirSqGhgIzxTga8TrkGhEQJd4t1e2P9bfzu4D1jD-wzUQw6lNHTrgWMrZpkAnfHezegtEzRLNPMbYnEt1R1oSgwWZWLX-QXAVBlwq_jlE%3D&vpol=pe&vflid=0&retURL=%2Fapex%2FMF_DP_PDFGenerator%3FassetId%3Da330I00000L8EzhQAF%26inline%3D1';
} 
} 
redirectOnLoad();
</script>```
````

Answer (score 3):

We identified the issue. The 'Session Security Level Required at Login = High Assurance' added at Profile level for Partner users to enforce MFA (High assurance session) was causing the issue i.e. asking for re verification in Async context (Future/Queueable) .

We updated it to "None" and instead checked **'Multi-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins'** in profile. It worked